# What language/technology/framework is Technorati built with?

Tags: architecture, web-applications

I see no obvious indicators like .php or .jsp or .aspx file extensions.

Anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

Their search page form posts to http://www.technorati.com/query.php so I would assume it's at least partially PHP.

Also [their ad system](http://beta.technoratimedia.com/) seems to be driven by ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

There's some info here on the architecture:

http://blogs.zdnet.com/Newton/?p=20

I believe it's PHP based.